# Use a dataframe column to join values of another column after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'group': list('ABBCA'),
        'values': list('xyztr'),
        'joiner': ['j1', 'j2', 'j2', 'j3', 'j1']
    }
)

  group values joiner
0     A      x     j1
1     B      y     j2
2     B      z     j2
3     C      t     j3
4     A      r     j1
```

I now want to groupby the column `group` and join the respective values in `values` using the entry in `joiner`. So something like this:

```
df.groupby('group')['values'].transform(" - ".join)

0    x - r
1    y - z
2    y - z
3        t
4    x - r
```

Just that instead `" - "` it should use the respective value in `df['joiner']`.

How would I do this?

Expected outcome would be:

```
0    x j1 r
1    y j2 z
2    y j2 z
3        t
4    x j1 r
```

We can safely assume that the `joiner` value is consistent with the `group` column (otherwise the `groupby` would fail).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df.groupby(['group', 'joiner'])['values']\
    .transform(lambda gr: (' ' + gr.name[1] + ' ').join(gr))
```

Answer (score 7):

here is one way:

```
m=df.groupby('group').agg({'values':list,'joiner':'first'})
s=pd.Series([f' {b} '.join(a) for a,b in zip(m['values'],m['joiner'])],index=m.index)
final=df.assign(new=df.group.map(s))
```

---

```
  group values joiner     new
0     A      x     j1  x j1 r
1     B      y     j2  y j2 z
2     B      z     j2  y j2 z
3     C      t     j3       t
4     A      r     j1  x j1 r
```

Answer (score 5):

Using a mapper and [`pd.Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)

```
mapper = df.set_index('group').joiner.to_dict()
df.groupby('group').values.transform(lambda s: s.str.cat(sep=f' {mapper[s.name]} '))
```

---

```
  group values joiner  joined
0     A      x     j1  x j1 r
1     B      y     j2  y j2 z
2     B      z     j2  y j2 z
3     C      t     j3       t
4     A      r     j1  x j1 r
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way

```
s=df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: (' '+x['joiner'].iloc[0]+ ' ').join(x['values'])).reindex(df.group)
group
A    x j1 r
B    y j2 z
B    y j2 z
C         t
A    x j1 r
dtype: object
df['new']=s.values
```